# Somebody Is Reporting Me as Hacking Stack Exchange

Tags: support, closed-questions, ios-app, hacked

At [one of my last answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361063/i-cannot-comprehend-any-math-i-cannot-understand-how-things-can-be-equal-yet-se/2361132#2361132) over an "on-hold" question, some users are reporting my current account as being hacking the site, claiming that "I answered a question already closed".

Why the app let me do that, is actually unknown, and honestly not relevant, to me.

Besides the obvious honoring title as "SE hackers", and the hilarious fact of hacking SE for "answering questions on hold of elementary level school students", what should I do to protect my account against this kind of actions?

If somebody is interested in the details:

- I am using SE from iPhone 5,
- My carrier is experiencing interruptions, due to snow storm,
- I am using Math Stack Exchange,
- I am answering a question within the app, during the "on hold" period.

Comment: Please tag properly in the future, the fact you're using the app is **crucial**.

Answer (score 12):

You're not hacking anything. :) Consequently, there's nothing to be done about "protecting your account". Your account is 100% fine.

There's a (relatively) short grace period for closed questions... if you already started writing an answer, it's possible that you can post it even if the question is closed in the meantime. If another user is making wild accusations against you, feel free to flag those comments for moderator attention so they can be removed.

---

*In general*, if you think you ran into a bug, you're welcome to post a report (with details - what you did, what you expected, what actually happened, etc) either here or on [Math's own meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com). And if you ever disagree with a moderator action, you can always discuss that on meta as well, or [reach out to us via "contact us" at the bottom of any page](/contact) for a review.

Comment: I'm about 95% sure this is just a normal grace period behavior, but I'll double-check tomorrow when I'm back at work vs idly checking meta on a Sunday night.

Comment: Yes this is normal. In the site, the submit button disappears when the live refresh detects the question got closed. The app does not perform such check. Pretty sure it was "reported" before, will search. Edit: found and closed.

Comment: Also, the grace period is 3 hours as far as I remember, not that short. :)

Answer (score 2):

### You should do nothing.

You report that one of other users are reporting you for hacking. *So what, who cares?*

What I mean is that community moderators *will not act without evidence*; perhaps you tripped a bug. Perhaps you were just *extremely lucky*, and submitted an answer moments before the final vote to close the question. Either way, you will not get banned for "hacking" simply due to a bug or other users reporting that you are. *You will only be banned if there is actual evidence*.

#### As per what you should do about the possible bug

As it stands, you may very well have encountered a bug. If you can provide links to the original post, with your answer, you should post an actual *bug report* detailing when and how it happened, and what one might do to reproduce it (if it is, at all, reproducible). This not only helps Stack Exchange ensure bugs like this do not happen again, but if it is not truly a bug, other users will inform you about why it happened.

<del>I personally can't work out the exact details of this case; having a look at your Stack Overflow account, I only see answers listed from as recent as May. You only posted this question 12 minutes ago, so I must assume that the original question has been nuked from the Stack Overflow account, or you are asking on behalf of a friend.</del><sup>1</sup>

Looking at [your answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2361132/258594), I can determine two facts.

1. The question was closed "3 hours ago", with a time stamp of `2017-07-17 00:35:50Z`.
2. You posted your answer "1 hour ago", with a time stamp of `2017-07-17 02:31:59Z`.

***Your answer was posted almost two hours after the question was closed***; this is *certainly* not the intended behaviour, and you should report it as a bug.

<sub><sup>1</sup> The user reports this as an issue with Stack Overflow, however, we have since determined that [the answer in question was posted at the Math Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2361132/258594).</sub>

Comment: It's a question on Math.SE, not SO.

Comment: @AdamLear, cheers for the update.

Comment: Actually yes this is by design, see dupes.

Comment: Because this is a vote community, if a minority of the users with the proper rights to ban somebody are wanting to do that, they will, with or without proofs, whether or not there is an actual bug. That is my actual concern

Comment: @hyprfrco, that sounds quite ludicrous, to be honest. Its like saying "Stack Exchange will give in to bullies"; do you think you could source any previous case of this actually happening?

Comment: Lets get it pasa by now... :)

Comment: @hyprfrco, I'm sorry. I don't understand you.